# How to update ver.5.38.1 webpack files without breaking current site?

Tags: webpack

I have been tasked to maintain a website I did not code. The site was made in Oct 2022.  The webpack is version 5.38.1. When I try to update the site I get tons of errors about unmet and incorrect peer dependencies. I have tried working the current webpack, deprecated webpacks. Node.js from versions 14 - 18. I don't know what to do. If I update the files to the latest version the site won't process the BUILD Task due to dependency issues. If I try to recreate the webpack 5.38.1 enviornment the site was created in -  the BUILD won't run due to outdated plugins.

The creators of the site required the following in their ReadME to update: Required software

1. Web Browser
2. Node.js v12.14.0 min [[download link]](https://nodejs.org/dist/v12.14.0/node-v12.14.0-x64.msi)
3. Yarn v1.22.5 min [[installation guide]](https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/install#windows-stable)
4. PHP 7.2 min [[download link]](https://www.php.net/downloads.php)
5. Composer [[download link]](https://getcomposer.org/download/)
6. PhpStorm

My package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "foundation-xy",
  "version": "1.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "browserslist": [
    "last 2 versions",
    "ie >= 9",
    "android >= 4.4",
    "ios >= 7"
  ],
  "prettier": {
    "singleQuote": true,
    "trailingComma": "es5",
    "semi": true
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">= 14"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack --progress --config build/webpack.prod.js",
    "build:production": "yarn run build --env production",
    "build:production:analyze": "yarn run build:production --analyze",
    "start": "node build/watch.js",
    "lint": "yarn run -s lint:scripts && yarn run -s lint:styles && yarn run -s lint:php",
    "lint:php": "vendor/bin/phpcs",
    "lint:scripts": "eslint assets/scripts",
    "lint:styles": "stylelint \"assets/styles/**/*.scss\"",
    "fix:php": "vendor/bin/php-cs-fixer --verbose fix --config .php_cs_fixer",
    "fix:scripts": "prettier --write \"assets/scripts/**/*.js\"",
    "fix:styles": "prettier --write \"assets/**/*.scss\""
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.14.5",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.14.5",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.2.6",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.2",
    "babel-minify-webpack-plugin": "^0.3.1",
    "browser-sync": "^2.26.14",
    "browser-sync-webpack-plugin": "^2.3.0",
    "browserslist": "^4.16.6",
    "cache-loader": "^4.1.0",
    "circular-dependency-plugin": "^5.2.2",
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.0",
    "copy-globs-webpack-plugin": "^0.3.0",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^9.0.0",
    "css-loader": "5.2.6",
    "cssnano": "5.0.6",
    "debug": "^4.3.1",
    "eslint": "^7.28.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.3.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.23.4",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "3.4.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "7.20.3",
    "eslint-webpack-plugin": "^2.5.4",
    "file-loader": "^6.2.0",
    "friendly-errors-webpack-plugin": "^1.7.0",
    "imagemin-mozjpeg": "^9.0.0",
    "imagemin-webpack-plugin": "^2.4.2",
    "import-glob": "^1.5.0",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^1.6.0",
    "node-sass": "^6.0.0",
    "object-fit-images": "^3.2.4",
    "optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin": "^6.0.0",
    "postcss": "^8.3.2",
    "postcss-loader": "^6.1.0",
    "postcss-safe-parser": "^5.0.2",
    "prettier": "^2.3.1",
    "ramda": "^0.27.1",
    "resolve-url-loader": "^4.0.0",
    "rimraf": "^3.0.2",
    "sass-loader": "^12.1.0",
    "select2": "^4.1.0-rc.0",
    "source-map-resolve": "^0.6.0",
    "style-loader": "^2.0.0",
    "stylelint": "^13.13.1",
    "stylelint-config-prettier": "^8.0.2",
    "stylelint-prettier": "^1.2.0",
    "stylelint-webpack-plugin": "^2.1.1",
    "url-loader": "^4.1.1",
    "vanilla-lazyload": "^17.4.0",
    "webpack": "^5.38.1",
    "webpack-assets-manifest": "^5.0.6",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^4.4.2",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.7.2",
    "webpack-dev-middleware": "^5.0.0",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "^2.25.0",
    "webpack-merge": "^5.8.0",
    "whatwg-fetch": "^3.6.2",
    "yargs": "^17.0.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@fancyapps/fancybox": "^3.5.7",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^5.15.3",
    "@wordpress/block-editor": "^8.1.1",
    "@wordpress/blocks": "^11.2.1",
    "@wordpress/data": "^6.2.1",
    "@wordpress/i18n": "^4.3.1",
    "aos": "^2.3.4",
    "foundation-sites": "^6.6.3",
    "jarallax": "^1.12.7",
    "jquery": "^3.5.1",
    "jquery-match-height": "^0.7.2",
    "motion-ui": "^2.0.3",
    "prop-types": "^15.8.1",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "scroll-out": "^2.2.12",
    "slick-carousel": "^1.8.1",
    "what-input": "^5.2.10"
  }
}
```

The first error I got after installing yarn and composer was `npx browserslist@latest --update-db`

Which I ran and got:

```
zsh: command not found: Browserslist:
Latest version:     1.0.30001521
Installed version:  1.0.30001312
Removing old caniuse-lite from lock file
Installing new caniuse-lite version
$ yarn add -W caniuse-lite
warning " > @wordpress/block-editor@8.1.1" has unmet peer dependency "react-dom@^17.0.0".
warning "@wordpress/block-editor > @react-spring/web@9.4.3" has unmet peer dependency "react-dom@^16.8.0  || ^17.0.0".
warning "@wordpress/block-editor > @wordpress/components@19.4.0" has unmet peer dependency "react-dom@^17.0.0".
warning "@wordpress/block-editor > react-autosize-textarea@7.1.0" has incorrect peer dependency "react@^0.14.0 || ^15.0.0 || ^16.0.0".
warning "@wordpress/block-editor > react-autosize-textarea@7.1.0" has unmet peer dependency "react-dom@^0.14.0 || ^15.0.0 || ^16.0.0".
warning "@wordpress/block-editor > react-easy-crop@3.5.3" has unmet peer dependency "react-dom@>=16.4.0".
warning "@wordpress/block-editor > @wordpress/components > framer-motion@4.1.17" has unmet peer dependency "react-dom@>=16.8 || ^17.0.0".
warning "@wordpress/block-editor > @wordpress/components > re-resizable@6.9.1" has unmet peer dependency "react-dom@^16.13.1 || ^17.0.0".
warning "@wordpress/block-editor > @wordpress/components > react-colorful@5.5.1" has unmet peer dependency "react-dom@>=16.8.0".
warning "@wordpress/block-editor > @wordpress/components > react-dates@17.2.0" has incorrect peer dependency "react@^0.14 || ^15.5.4 || ^16.1.1".
warning "@wordpress/block-editor > @wordpress/components > react-dates@17.2.0" has unmet peer dependency "react-dom@^0.14 || ^15.5.4 || ^16.1.1".
warning "@wordpress/block-editor > @wordpress/components > reakit@1.3.11" has unmet peer dependency "react-dom@^16.8.0 || ^17.0.0".
warning "@wordpress/block-editor > @wordpress/components > react-dates > airbnb-prop-types@2.16.0" has incorrect peer dependency "react@^0.14 || ^15.0.0 || ^16.0.0-alpha".
warning "@wordpress/block-editor > @wordpress/components > react-dates > react-outside-click-handler@1.3.0" has unmet peer dependency "react-dom@^0.14 || >=15".
warning "@wordpress/block-editor > @wordpress/components > react-dates > react-with-styles@3.2.3" has unmet peer dependency "react-with-direction@^1.1.0".
warning "@wordpress/block-editor > @wordpress/components > reakit > reakit-system@0.15.2" has unmet peer dependency "react-dom@^16.8.0 || ^17.0.0".
warning "@wordpress/block-editor > @wordpress/components > reakit > reakit-utils@0.15.2" has unmet peer dependency "react-dom@^16.8.0 || ^17.0.0".
warning "@wordpress/block-editor > @wordpress/components > react-dates > react-with-styles > react-with-direction@1.4.0" has incorrect peer dependency "react@^0.14 || ^15 || ^16".
warning "@wordpress/block-editor > @wordpress/components > react-dates > react-with-styles > react-with-direction@1.4.0" has unmet peer dependency "react-dom@^0.14 || ^15 || ^16".
warning " > babel-minify-webpack-plugin@0.3.1" has incorrect peer dependency "webpack@^2.0.0 || ^3.0.0 || ^4.0.0".
warning " > cache-loader@4.1.0" has incorrect peer dependency "webpack@^4.0.0".
warning " > friendly-errors-webpack-plugin@1.7.0" has incorrect peer dependency "webpack@^2.0.0 || ^3.0.0 || ^4.0.0".
warning " > optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin@6.0.0" has incorrect peer dependency "webpack@^4.0.0".
Cleaning package.json dependencies from caniuse-lite
$ yarn remove -W caniuse-lite
warning " > @wordpress/block-editor@8.1.1" has unmet peer dependency "react-dom@^17.0.0".
warning "@wordpress/block-editor > @react-spring/web@9.4.3" has unmet peer dependency "react-dom@^16.8.0  || ^17.0.0".
warning "@wordpress/block-editor > @wordpress/components@19.4.0" has unmet peer dependency "react-dom@^17.0.0".
warning "@wordpress/block-editor > react-autosize-textarea@7.1.0" has incorrect peer dependency "react@^0.14.0 || ^15.0.0 || ^16.0.0".
warning "@wordpress/block-editor > react-autosize-textarea@7.1.0" has unmet peer dependency "react-dom@^0.14.0 || ^15.0.0 || ^16.0.0".
warning "@wordpress/block-editor > react-easy-crop@3.5.3" has unmet peer dependency "react-dom@>=16.4.0".
warning "@wordpress/block-editor > @wordpress/components > framer-motion@4.1.17" has unmet peer dependency "react-dom@>=16.8 || ^17.0.0".
warning "@wordpress/block-editor > @wordpress/components > re-resizable@6.9.1" has unmet peer dependency "react-dom@^16.13.1 || ^17.0.0".
warning "@wordpress/block-editor > @wordpress/components > react-colorful@5.5.1" has unmet peer dependency "react-dom@>=16.8.0".
warning "@wordpress/block-editor > @wordpress/components > react-dates@17.2.0" has incorrect peer dependency "react@^0.14 || ^15.5.4 || ^16.1.1".
warning "@wordpress/block-editor > @wordpress/components > react-dates@17.2.0" has unmet peer dependency "react-dom@^0.14 || ^15.5.4 || ^16.1.1".
warning "@wordpress/block-editor > @wordpress/components > reakit@1.3.11" has unmet peer dependency "react-dom@^16.8.0 || ^17.0.0".
warning "@wordpress/block-editor > @wordpress/components > react-dates > airbnb-prop-types@2.16.0" has incorrect peer dependency "react@^0.14 || ^15.0.0 || ^16.0.0-alpha".
warning "@wordpress/block-editor > @wordpress/components > react-dates > react-outside-click-handler@1.3.0" has unmet peer dependency "react-dom@^0.14 || >=15".
warning "@wordpress/block-editor > @wordpress/components > react-dates > react-with-styles@3.2.3" has unmet peer dependency "react-with-direction@^1.1.0".
warning "@wordpress/block-editor > @wordpress/components > reakit > reakit-system@0.15.2" has unmet peer dependency "react-dom@^16.8.0 || ^17.0.0".
warning "@wordpress/block-editor > @wordpress/components > reakit > reakit-utils@0.15.2" has unmet peer dependency "react-dom@^16.8.0 || ^17.0.0".
warning "@wordpress/block-editor > @wordpress/components > react-dates > react-with-styles > react-with-direction@1.4.0" has incorrect peer dependency "react@^0.14 || ^15 || ^16".
warning "@wordpress/block-editor > @wordpress/components > react-dates > react-with-styles > react-with-direction@1.4.0" has unmet peer dependency "react-dom@^0.14 || ^15 || ^16".
warning " > babel-minify-webpack-plugin@0.3.1" has incorrect peer dependency "webpack@^2.0.0 || ^3.0.0 || ^4.0.0".
warning " > cache-loader@4.1.0" has incorrect peer dependency "webpack@^4.0.0".
warning " > friendly-errors-webpack-plugin@1.7.0" has incorrect peer dependency "webpack@^2.0.0 || ^3.0.0 || ^4.0.0".
warning " > optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin@6.0.0" has incorrect peer dependency "webpack@^4.0.0".
caniuse-lite has been successfully updated

No target browser changes
```

I have worked for days trying to figure this out. Any help at all would be amazing.

When I try to update the site I get tons of errors about unmet and incorrect peer dependencies. I have tried working the current webpack, deprecated webpacks. Node.js from versions 14 - 18. Ultimately I am trying to run the BUILD function on my scss file to put it in the DEV folder so I can put that folder onto the site. That is what the README file said to do. I can't get that to work.

If I update the files to the latest version the site won't process the BUILD Task due to dependency issues. If I try to recreate the webpack 5.38.1 enviornment the site was created in -  the BUILD won't run due to outdated plugins.